# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una función para este programa?

Tags: php

Necesito hacer un programa de venta de autos, en el que al hacer click en el botón comprar de un modelo me aparezca debajo el precio del modelo. Según el botón seleccionado, se imprime el determinado precio. Lo había echo tratado de hacer con un input no editable, pero no salió bien.
En realidad el programa es más largo pero por ahora voy en esa parte. Había logrado que funcionara pero se me borró y lo tengo que hacer de nuevo, y no recuerdo como lo había hecho. Espero me puedan ayudar.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Venta de Autos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo '<img src="KIA Logo.png" width="390x" height="100x"><br>';
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <?php
            function precio(){
                if ($_POST){
                    $opcion =$_POST['btnEl'];
                    switch ($opcion){
                        case 'Comprar KIA Soul':
                            $precio = '$470,000 MXN';
                            echo "Precio:", $precio;
                            break;
                        case 'Comprar KIA EV6':
                            $precio = '$1,900,000 MXN';
                            echo "Precio:", $precio;
                            break;
                        case 'Comprar KIA K9':
                            $precio = '$1,200,000 MXN';
                            echo "Precio:", $precio;
                            break;
                        case 'Comprar KIA Sportage':
                            $precio = '$600,000 MXN';
                            echo "Precio:", $precio;
                            break;
                        default:
                            echo "Error";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } 
        ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        echo '<img src="KIA Soul.png" width="270x" height="150x"> <br>';
                    ?>
                    KIA Soul</br>
                    <p><input type="submit" name="btnEl" value="Comprar KIA Soul">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        echo '<img src="KIA EV6.png" width="250x" height="150x"> <br>';
                    ?>
                    KIA EV6</br> 
                    <p><input type="submit" name="btnEl" value="Comprar KIA EV6">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        echo '<img src="KIA K9.png" width="250x" height="150x"> <br>';
                    ?>
                    KIA K9</br> 
                    <p><input type="submit" name="btnEl" value="Comprar KIA K9">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        echo '<img src="KIA Sportage.png" width="250x" height="150x"> <br>';
                    ?>
                    KIA Sportage</br> 
                    <p><input type="submit" name="btnEl" value="Comprar KIA Sportage">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
            precio();
        ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo falta agregar la llamada a `precio()` para que aparezca el procesamiento de la opcion que viene del `$_POST`:

```
    <?php
        function precio(){
            if ($_POST) {
                $opcion =$_POST['btnEl'];
                switch ($opcion){
                    case 'Comprar KIA Soul':
                        $precio = '$470,000 MXN';
                        echo "Precio:", $precio;
                        break;
                    case 'Comprar KIA EV6':
                        $precio = '$1,900,000 MXN';
                        echo "Precio:", $precio;
                        break;
                    case 'Comprar KIA K9':
                        $precio = '$470,000 MXN';
                        echo "Precio:", $precio;
                        break;
                    case 'Comprar KIA Sportage':
                        $precio = '$1,900,000 MXN';
                        echo "Precio:", $precio;
                        break;
                    default:
                        echo "Error";
                        break;
                }
            }
        } 
        precio(); // llamar la funcion
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que fallan en tu código:

1. Solamente puedes llamar a la función `precio()` desde PHP, que es donde la has declarado, y no con Javascript utilizando el `onclick` de los botones.
2. Tal y como planteas el código, incluyendo los modelos y precios directamente en él, no tiene mucho sentido utilizar PHP ni tampoco recargar la página enviando un formulario, puedes hacerlo solo utilizando Javascript.

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```js
// Esta función se incluye en cada `onclick` y se le debe pasar como parámetro el importe del coche
function precio(importe) {
  // Obtener el campo de solo lectura donde imprimir el importe
  const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  // Formatear el importe que se le pasa a la función
  const formateado = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX', { style: 'currency', currency: 'MXN' }).format(importe);
  // Imprimir el importe formateado en el campo de solo lectura
  resultado.value = formateado + ' MXN';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado" readonly></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>KIA Soul</td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="precio(470000);">Comprar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>KIA EV6</td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="precio(1900000);">Comprar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>KIA K9</td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="precio(470000);">Comprar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>KIA Sportage</td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="precio(1900000);">Comprar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```